# Pinescript backtest on multiple symbols in a single script?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I've a working strategy that I would like to test on different forex pairs but switching between all of this by hand is quite time consuming (also between timeframes).

So I'm trying to look for a way to do it, all in my script.

I've read that I can use something like this : `AUDCAD_DAILY = security("OANDA:AUDCAD", "D", close)` to get a specific timeframe and a specific symbol.

But now here's come the question : Is it possible to create 28 different lines like this and backtest all of them at the same time (in 1 script) ? If yes, how ?